# Mac .app Fails in a function call to 3rd party lib on Lion. But works when run from the .app/Contents/MacOs/executable

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am trying to run our App on Mac Lion. App is built on Snow Leopard 10.6.8, packaged using package maker. We are linking dynamically to libCurl(3rd party lib). On snow leopard it works. On Lion when I install and click the app icon it fails in call to curl_easy_perform (from libCurl). But when I right click the app icon, click show package contents, and goto /Applications/MyDir/OurApp.app/Contents/MacOS/OurApp and then try to run that unix executable, then it works. I used otool to check the lib paths and they all seem correct.

Can someone help me why it fails when I click the .app? I thought .app is a soft link to the main executable. so if the executable works, then .app should also work.

Do I have to tell the path of the lib in .app? if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic linker "dyld" and related programs such as "otool" are influenced by environment variables.  Environment variables can vary by process: the Finder has a unique copy of environment variable settings, and so does each shell in a terminal window.

As you can see if you run "man dyld", there are many variables that can influence the behavior of these programs.

If you're seeing different behavior from the command line than in the Finder, I imagine that at least one of the special linker variables has been set in your terminal.  It is probably instructing the linker to look in places for libraries that are different from the linker's defaults (or whatever the Finder uses).

You can run "env | sort" from your terminal to see what's been set.